When I use MapStruct's qualifiedByName and @Named doesn't take effect
MapStruct version is 1.5.5.Final,JDK is 17,Here is my code
@Mapper
public interface UndoIssueConvert {
    UndoIssueConvert INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UndoIssueConvert.class);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "undoIssueId", source = "id"),
//          @Mapping(target = "createTime", expression = ("java(undoIssue.getUpdateTime() != null ? undoIssue.getUpdateTime() : undoIssue.getCreateTime())"))
            @Mapping(target = "createTime", qualifiedByName = "convertCreateTime")
    })
    UndoIssuePanelRspVO.UndoIssue toUndoIssue(UndoIssue undoIssue);

    List<UndoIssuePanelRspVO.UndoIssue> toUndoIssue(List<UndoIssue> undoIssue);

    @Named("convertCreateTime")
    default Date convertCreateTime(UndoIssue undoIssue) {
        return undoIssue.getUpdateTime() != null ? undoIssue.getUpdateTime() : undoIssue.getCreateTime();
    }

    UndoIssue toUndoIssueEntity(UndoIssueAddUpdateVO addVO);
}

But I get the following exception
java: Qualifier error. No method found annotated with @Named#value: [ convertCreateTime ]

I confirmed the annotation path is correct

The problem in your case is that the convertCreateTime method expects the entire UndoIssue object.
Instead of passing the entire UndoIssue object to the convertCreateTime method, you must pass the required fields directly.
Here is the solution way shown below
Changed @Mapping(target = "createTime", qualifiedByName = "convertCreateTime") to @Mapping(target = "createTime", source = ".", qualifiedByName = "convertCreateTime")
Here is the updated your code shown below
@Mapper
public interface UndoIssueConvert {
    UndoIssueConvert INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UndoIssueConvert.class);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "undoIssueId", source = "id"),
            @Mapping(target = "createTime", source = ".", qualifiedByName = "convertCreateTime")
    })
    UndoIssuePanelRspVO.UndoIssue toUndoIssue(UndoIssue undoIssue);

    List<UndoIssuePanelRspVO.UndoIssue> toUndoIssue(List<UndoIssue> undoIssue);

    @Named("convertCreateTime")
    default Date convertCreateTime(UndoIssue undoIssue) {
        return undoIssue.getUpdateTime() != null ? undoIssue.getUpdateTime() : undoIssue.getCreateTime();
    }

    UndoIssue toUndoIssueEntity(UndoIssueAddUpdateVO addVO);
}

